# FitNesse Wiki Per Project or Company?

Tags: fitnesse

For a company with many development projects, should you create multiple FitNesse wikis (one for each project/product) or contain them all within a large wiki for everything?

Advantages of one large wiki is the ability to easily link to other products in the company and that it is a one-stop location for all the FitNesse tests.

Alternatively, the advantages of multiple wikis is it becomes easier to divide automation of the tests to multiple servers, it becomes easier to branch the wiki along with a project branch / tag.

I'm interested in the advantages and disadvantages of these two possibilities or a well thought out alternative (e.g. not "just combine the wiki roots together somehow").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it all boils down to an administration problem:
How many servers are available out there and who manages them ?
One central server mean a server able to take the load, both in term of requests (all developers from all projects can make many queries on a fairly regular base), and in term of "on-server" FitNesse-related computations.

Another criteria is the visibility. Do your development projects *need* to see each other FitNesse indicators ? For "political" reason, some of those indicators may not be always welcome to be seen at all time by the rest of the projects! Some project manager might want to keep them close to the vest and control their official communication.

Actually, it is for the latter reason our FitNesses wikis are managed by each teams, more as an internal tool. We have another global wiki (based on [Confluance](http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/)), for managing global documentation for each projects. Those common wikis may extract some of the internal FitNesse wiki data.